# A word or expression for "Waiting until the opportune moment"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a word (that may or may not exist, I haven't found it yet) that describes waiting for an opportune moment. Something like a snake that hides from it's prey until it's the right time to strike.

Or like "not showing your cards too early", something like this.

In chinese there are 2 symbols that translate to what I'm looking for:

伺機 (English: Wait for an opportunity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "bide your time" is to wait patiently for a good opportunity to do something.

[Bide your time (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bide-your-time)

Answer (score 1):

**To bide one's time** is probably the best choice.

Another one is:

**To sit tight:** (1) to remain in place in readiness or expectation of something, (2) to remain out of sight

[Sit tight (Meriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/sit%20tight)

Examples:
We're planning to **sit tight** until the end of the game.

He told us to **sit tight** and wait for the captain's signal.